# Invoking Java EE web services from iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to invoke Java EE web services from iPhone? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hasn't been formally updated in a while, but this [project](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) can be used to access traditional SOAP web services. I have used it in production.

Comment: Make sure you read the related discussion group: http://groups.google.com/group/wsdl2objc-discuss

Answer (score 0):

And I wrote two tutorials for wsdl2objc: they're [here](http://brismith66.blogspot.com/search/label/iPhone%20Development)